# Array Formula to omit certain values

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm currently using the following array formula in `B2` - `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(LEN(F15:F114&L15:L114 ), IF((N(F15:F114))+(N(L15:L114 ))>0, 1, 0), )))`
The `F` and `L` columns referenced are all tick boxes and this formula is counting those boxes that are checked. It allows me to count the `F` and `L` tick boxes as one irrelevant of whether 1 of them or both of them are checked. I'm now looking to expand on this by introducing the ability for the formula to disregard counting the tick boxes of a specific row if the `B` column of that row states "Scrapped". So as an example using rows 15 and 16 - if `B15` states "Active" and `F15` and `L15` are ticked, then that will add one to the count in `B2`, however if `B16` states "Scrapped" and `F16` and `L16` are ticked it still won't count towards the count in `B2`. To omit certain values in the past I've added <>"" to the formula but can't seem to make that work in this one so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(LEN(F15:F114&L15:L114), 
 IF(((N(F15:F114))+(N(L15:L114))*(B15:B114<>"Scrapped"))>0, 1, 0), )))
```

Comment: Could this array be easily amended so that instead of omitting the count of rows that have "Scrapped" in column ```B```, only those rows with "Scrapped" in column ```B``` are counted @player0 ? Been having a play around with it to see but no success so far unfortunately so thought I would turn to you guys for help again

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with example?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BKcOxHx4G_cf9n2z1XptqiOGPZ9HLo9qIfyy5GaQhJg/edit?usp=sharing   ...….hopefully this link works - feel free to play around with it as I've set it as a test sheet. The formula I am trying to amend is in ```B4```. Originally I just wanted it to count if the B column states "Scrapped" and the L column equals "TRUE" but now I have extended my sheet, I need it to count 1 in ```B4``` whether any of columns L, P, T, X or AB are "TRUE" or if some or all of them are marked "TRUE"

Comment: It is similar to the formula you came up with for me in ```B2``` which I have been able to extend to my new columns but instead of omitting those with "scrapped" in the B column I want it to only count those rows with "Scrapped" in the B column

Comment: That's the formula I use in ```B2``` which allows me to count "TRUE" entries in the G,L,P,T,X & AB columns unless it states "Scrapped" in the B column. For ```B4``` I'm looking for those same columns to be only counted if it states "Scrapped" in the B column - I thought I could amend the formula you put above to remove the ```<>"Scrapped" ``` and replace it with ```="Scrapped" ``` but no luck with that unfortunately

Comment: I see, try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(LEN(G10:G203&L10:L203&P10:P203&T10:T203&X10:X203&AB10:AB203), IF(((N(G10:G203))+(N(L10:L203))+(N(P10:P203))+(N(T10:T203))+(N(X10:X203))+(N(AB10:AB203 )))*(B10:B203="Scrapped")>0, 1, 0), )))` - there were parenthesis on a wrong spots